# Obtener ultimo costo por artículo MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente tabla :

[image: art]

necesito traer solamente Art, Costo_COS de cada artículo donde el COSTO_COS sea el que tiene la FECM Mayor. Es decir, una fila por artículo.

Ejemplo:
| ART      | COSTO_COS      |
| 5        | 133.7750       |
| 11       | 0.0000         |

Estoy trabajando con MYSQL. Agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas hacer una subconsulta que te diga la fecha máxima (FECM) agrupándola por artículo (ART). Esto te va a dar una sola fila por artículo. Esta subconsulta la unes (mediante un `JOIN`) con la consulta principal igualando artículo y FECM.

```
SELECT ART, COSTO_COS, FechasMax.FechaMax as FECM
FROM Tabla
JOIN (
    SELECT ART, MAX(FECM) as FechaMax
    FROM Tabla
    GROUP BY ART
) as FechasMax on Tabla.ART = FechasMax.ART and Tabla.FECM = FechasMax.FechaMax;
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes conseguirlo con una subconsulta sobre la misma tabla, según quieras fecha mayor o menor puedes utilizar MIN o MAX.

```html
SELECT 
    t1.ART, t1.COSTO_COS
FROM    
    table t1
WHERE
    t1.FECM = (SELECT MIN(FECM) FROM table t2 WHERE t1.ART = t2.ART);
```